# Hugo (go static site generator) list for specific URLs

Tags: go, hugo

let's say I have the following structure

```
content
- blog-folder-1
-- blog-article-1-1.md
-- blog-article-1-2.md
- blog-folder-2
-- blog-article-2-1.md
-- blog-article-2-2.md
```

Then I also have the `layouts/_default/list.html` file which will be called every time I visit the URLs `example.com/`, `example.com/blog-topic-1/`, and `example.com/blod-topic-2/`

So the problem I have is that I don't want the `layouts/_default/list.html` file to generate the same content for these different paths..

I overcame the problem of only displaying certain articles in the homepage by adding `++ displayHomepage = "true" ++`  to the .md files and `{{ range $index, $page := first 50 (where .Site.Pages.ByPublishDate ".Params.displayHomepage" "true") }}` to the `list.html` file, but I can't figure out what to do if I don't want to display `blog-article-2-1.md` when visiting `example.com/blog-folder-1/`

Any help would be greatly appreciated <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point the documentation is a little bit hard to order. I am going to link the important topics to the hugo documentation so that you are able to read more details. After looking to your [Content Organisation](http://gohugo.io/content/organization/) there are two [Sections](http://gohugo.io/content/sections/):

- blog-folder-1
- blog-folder-2

So inside your theme you are able to [define one template for each section](http://gohugo.io/templates/content/). If there is no template provided hugo uses the default.

So inside your layouts folder there is that logic: `/layouts/SECTION/LAYOUT.html`

For your case you can define a default layout. When for example blog-folder-2 needs another template your structure would look like this:

```
layouts/
  ▾ _default/
      single.html
  ▾ blog-folder-2/
      single.html
```

If you want to filter out one section inside a list, you need to use the [page variables](http://gohugo.io/templates/variables/).

At that points where you are ranging over the sites you can add a where clause:

```
 {{ range $i, $p := (.Paginate (where .Data.Pages "Section" "!=" "blog-folder-2")).Pages }}
```

Comment: Ahh, so that's what they meant with those sections, I thought it was related to something completely different.. thanks a lot! I think those sections would become a lot more clear/easier to understand if it was better highlighted that it was related to changing the content of specific .md files/content folders

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm misunderstanding.. but is it not possible to use this method with list.html? I tried creating the blog-folder-2 inside the layouts folder and placed a list.html file.. but it seems like it's being ignored?

Comment: It is to do that you need to range like that: ` {{ range $i, $p := (.Paginate (where .Data.Pages "Section" "!=" "blog-folder-2")).Pages  }}

Comment: Hmm, feel quite confused.. if I want all the content folders (x.com/, x.com/blog-folder-1/, and x.com/blog-folder-2/) to have their unique list.html file, then all the rules should be defined inside the layouts/_default/list.html file? or should I also create list.html files in the layouts/blog-folder-1/list.html and layouts/blog-folder-2/list.html folders?

Comment: For instance, in _defaults/list.html I have {{ range $index, $page := first 50 (where .Site.Pages.ByPublishDate ".Params.displayHomepage" "true") }}, in blog-folder-1/list.html I have {{ range $index, $page := first 50 (where .Site.Pages.ByPublishDate ".Params.displayBlog1" "true") }}, etc..? To me this makes sense, but it doesn't seem to be working.. so I'm thinking everything need to be written inside the _defaults/list.html file which makes it really complicated..

Comment: Okay, I figured it out.. it seems that instead of creating the file: layouts/blog-folder-1/list.html then instead I should create the file layouts/section/blog-folder-1.html... a little confused why they choose to do it that way but it works.. thanks again for everything :)